# Beta test of the game in the play market

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, upload, google-play, google-developers-console

I posted the game in the play market in a beta test, after I decided to transfer it to a working one, but in the market it writes near the name "beta test". What did I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, if you open Google Play from a different browser where you are not logged in, then the app will not be shown as Beta. So for any non-beta testers viewing it for the first time on their phone or via browser it's going to show up correctly.

If this occurred from the user's account side, it's because if one specific account subscribed to a beta program it will show as (BETA) on the Google Play Store. So, to remove the beta the user just has to do the following:

- Open the Google Play Store on the device.
- Find the app he wants to leave.
- Tap the app to open the detail page for the app.
- Scroll down to find the section on beta testing.
- Tap Leave.

Another thing you can try is to clear Google Play store's cache by navigating to "settings -> apps -> view all -> google play".